# Fail to expand points with \expandafter

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

As `pst-3dplot` has no named 3D points (aka 3D nodes), I have to use macros as follows. Unfortunately, the expansion is confusing. Could you fix it?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\psset
{
    Alpha=30,
    Beta=30,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(10,10)
    \pstThreeDCoor
    [
        xMin=-1,
        xMax=5,
        yMin=-1,
        yMax=5,
        zMin=-1,
        zMax=5,
        IIIDticks,
        IIIDticksize=.1,
        IIIDlabels,
    ]
    \def\A{(5,0,0)}
    \def\B{(5,5,0)}
    \def\C{(0,5,0)}
    \def\D{(0,0,0)}
    \def\E{(5,0,5)}
    \def\F{(5,5,5)}
    \def\G{(0,5,5)}
    \def\H{(0,0,5)}
    \foreach \i in {A,B,...,H}{\expandafter\pstThreeDDot\csname\i\endcsname}
    \expandafter\pstThreeDBox\D\A\C\H
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The expansion of `\csname\i\endcsname` is `\A` if you need (5,0,0) then you need three `\expandafter`

Comment: you'd need a lot more expandafter or use edef as in the answer below (or `\expanded` if you want to be terribly modern)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\psset
{
    Alpha=30,
    Beta=30,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(10,10)
    \pstThreeDCoor
    [
        xMin=-1,
        xMax=5,
        yMin=-1,
        yMax=5,
        zMin=-1,
        zMax=5,
        IIIDticks,
        IIIDticksize=.1,
        IIIDlabels,
    ]
    \def\A{(5,0,0)}
    \def\B{(5,5,0)}
    \def\C{(0,5,0)}
    \def\D{(0,0,0)}
    \def\E{(5,0,5)}
    \def\F{(5,5,5)}
    \def\G{(0,5,5)}
    \def\H{(0,0,5)}
    \foreach \i in {A,B,...,H}{\edef\coor{\csname\i\endcsname}\expandafter\pstThreeDDot\coor}
    \edef\coor{\D\A\C\H}
    \expandafter\pstThreeDBox\coor
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be overkill, but you can think to different applications.

```latex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\coords}{m}
 {
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mapcoords}{m}
 {
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { #1##2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usecoords}{mm}
 {
  \use:x { \exp_not:N #1 \tl_map_function:nN { #2 } \__mop_item:n }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__mop_item:n { \prop_item:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\psset{
  Alpha=30,
  Beta=30,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(10,10)
  \pstThreeDCoor[
    xMin=-1,
    xMax=5,
    yMin=-1,
    yMax=5,
    zMin=-1,
    zMax=5,
    IIIDticks,
    IIIDticksize=.1,
    IIIDlabels,
  ]
  \coords{
    A={(5,0,0)},
    B={(5,5,0)},
    C={(0,5,0)},
    D={(0,0,0)},
    E={(5,0,5)},
    F={(5,5,5)},
    G={(0,5,5)},
    H={(0,0,5)}
  }
  \mapcoords{\pstThreeDDot}
  \usecoords{\pstThreeDBox}{DACH}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

With `\coords` I store the coordinates in a property list; `\mapcoords` uses all coordinates by feeding them to the macro given as argument. With `\usecoords` you can use any number of names (a name not consisting of a single letter should be braced), feeding the corresponding coordinates to the macro given as first argument.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!